# Coherence theorem for tetracategories, weak $n$-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

Is there a coherence theorem/conjecture for tetracategories (weak $4$-categories)?

Todd Trimble mentions in his [notes](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/trimble/tetracategories.html) on tetracategories that his pasting definitions are essentially unambiguous due to the tricategorical coherence theorem of Gordon-Power-Street, and more than a decade has passed since then.

Does the current state of the art have a coherence conjecture/theorem for tetracategories, or even all weak $n$-categories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many things can be called a "coherence theorem", but I presume you're looking for one that's analogous to the GPS result that every fully-weak 3-category is equivalent to a [semistrict](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semi-strict+infinity-category) one in which associativity and units are strict but not interchange.  I don't think any theorem of this sort has been proven for $n\gt 3$, but recently there is at least a [proposal](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/associative%20n-category) for a class of semistrict $n$-categories that could in theory be the target of such a coherence theorem.

Comment: Much appreciated Mike, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Is a conjectured coherence theorem of this sort for fully weak infinity categories still out of reach, or would you expect the above conjecture for semistrict $n$-categories (if true) to yield a coherence theorem for weak infinity categories as well?

Comment: I wouldn't expect the $n$-categorical version to *yield* the $\infty$-categorical one in the sense of the latter being a consequence of the former (although I suppose there could be some game you could play), but I expect similar methods could be used to formulate an analogous conjecture, and if the one could be proven then maybe the other could too.